# Solving $div(A)=B$ for unkown $A$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, vector-analysis, discrete-calculus

I'm mechanical PhD student and I'm trying to solve the following problem discretized on the domain $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$. Find $D$ such that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\rho D\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\rho D\frac{\partial c}{\partial y}\right)=A$$
knowing $\rho$, $c$ and $A$ in each point of the domain. the boundary conditions are assumed to be periodic.

Initially, I discretized the equation and obtain a matrix for $D_i^j$ values ($D_i^j=D(x(i),y(j))$. But, the main problem comes out when the gradient of $c$ is null.

Comment: What is the problem specifically though? the way I see it if the gradient of "c" is null, knowing "c" in every point you can still approximate it by expanding the equation and using the Hessian of "c" (which you can approximate I presume)

Comment: @Snifkes: I just specified that the question is to find $D$ which represent the diffusivity of the scalar $c$.

Comment: Well I am not sure about the specific values. But from what I see: under a discretized form, you will have a set of linear relationships involving D_{ ij } which you transform into a matrix. By inverting this matrix, you may obtain the values for D that you want. However, I still do not see what is the problem with the gradient of "c" being null at some points (as you mention in your problem definition).